# Delete selected row in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to delete a selected row in DataTable. Code I am using is:

```
var oTable = jQuery("#tableId").dataTable();
jQuery("#tableId tbody').on( 'click','.delete',  function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        oTable.row(jQuery(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw( false );

} );
```

But I am getting this error:

> 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'oTable.row('.deleteNow')');

Is there anything I am missing or anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of intializing datatable as

```
var oTable = jQuery("#tableId").dataTable();
```

Try

```
var oTable = jQuery("#tableId").DataTable(); //use 'D' instead of 'd'
```

Answer (score 0):

delete_bookmark is delete button id 
mbot0 is table row class try this

```
$(document).on('click','.delete_bookmark',function(){
        $(this).closest(".mbot0").remove();
    });
```